# Adding fourth table in mysql join

Tags: mysql, select, join, left-join, inner-join

I have written a query which involves 3 joins and 3 tables as follows:

```
SELECT 
T3.fault, count(*)
FROM table2 T2 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT a.*
    FROM table1 a
    LEFT JOIN table1 b ON a.item_id = b.item_id AND a.submit_id < b.submit_id
    WHERE b.submit_id IS NULL
) T1  ON T1.item_id = T2.item_id
INNER JOIN table3 T3 ON T1.id = T3.run_id
group by T3.fault
order by count(*) desc;
```

My `table3` looks as follows:

```
id      run_id  runname_id  status  fault
134049  16736   312         FAIL    error1
134050  16736   313         FAIL    error2
134051  16736   314         FAIL    error3
134052  16736   315         PASS    error4
134053  16736   316         PASS    error5
```

I have a static table `table4` which looks as follows:

```
id  name
312 name1
313 name2
314 name3
315 name4
316 name5
```

I want to include `table4` in the query so that my output should also include `name` from `table4`. Every `error` has a corresponding `name` in `table4` I want to include that name as well

```
fault   count(*) name
error1  6        name1
```

Comment: Error1 may relate to multiple runs. Which name or names do you want to include in the resultset?

Comment: If `T3.fault` is not a candidate key (`UNIQUE NOT NULL`), then it doesn't make sense and mysql might not even allow that. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html

Comment: okay. i thought it includes adding another inner join to table3 on `runname_id`

Comment: To be more specific: Replace `error2` in the second row of `table3` with `error1` (so that `error1` appears two times). What `name` from `table4` do you expect to see in the result set in the same row with `error1`? And why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So just `LEFT JOIN` that `table4`, and `T4.name` column to selected columns list.

```
SELECT 
T3.fault, count(*), t4.name
FROM table2 T2 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT a.*
    FROM table1 a
    LEFT JOIN table1 b ON a.item_id = b.item_id AND a.submit_id < b.submit_id
    WHERE b.submit_id IS NULL
) T1  ON T1.item_id = T2.item_id
INNER JOIN table3 T3 ON T1.id = T3.run_id
LEFT JOIN table4 T4
ON 3.runname_id  = T4.id
group by T3.fault
order by count(*) desc;
```

Comment: Since "Every error has a corresponding name in table4 I want to include that name as well" you should inner join T4.

Comment: @philipxy that is your personal opinion. I have mine. And I see that this  `LEFT JOIN` is absolutely fair here. and corresponding `name` is included **T4.name**

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this.

```
SELECT A.fault, A.count, T4.name FROM TABLE4 T4 JOIN(
SELECT 
T3.fault as fault, count(*) as count, T3.run_id as run_id
FROM table2 T2 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT a.*
    FROM table1 a
    LEFT JOIN table1 b ON a.item_id = b.item_id AND a.submit_id < b.submit_id
    WHERE b.submit_id IS NULL
) T1  ON T1.item_id = T2.item_id
INNER JOIN table3 T3 ON T1.id = T3.run_id
group by T3.fault) A ON A.run_id = T4.id
order by A.count desc;
```

Haven't tested it, but as far as I understand it's just merging 4th table with the sub query table. So your query would return result with fault, count and id. Then we just merge this table with table 4 on id and order the count by desc. 
Please correct me if I have wrong understanding of the question